# How should I set up volumes for multi-task database service in docker swarm?

Tags: mysql, docker, database, storage, docker-swarm

I am new to Docker and I want to do mini-project with Docker Swarm. I built docker image with my Django app. In dockerfile I added project files, migrated all models, and then ran server. Now it is time to prepare SQL database for django as a new service in stack. Now I am using only one replica build from MariaDB image. It has env vars needed to configure database, and mounted one local volume to store data on machine where container is running. In django settings I changed DB backend to mysql and DB host to name of database service. At this moment everything is working well.

But what If I want to have more replicas of DB engine? How should I deal with store data from diffrent nodes? If I use present configuration, data stored on first node won`t be the same as on second node.

And here is a question: How should I configure volume in compose-file to let all tasks use the same data.

I read some blogs and discussions where many people says, docker swarm is not good orchestrator to handle with DB, but is it really true?.

Current compose-file:

```
version: "3"

services:

    django-site:
            image: questionsite:maria
            ports:
                    - 8080:8080
            deploy:
                    replicas: 1
            depends_on:
                    - database
            networks:
                    - site

    database:
            image: mariadb:latest
            ports:
                    - 3306:3306
            networks:
                    - site
            deploy:
                    replicas: 1
            environment:
                    MYSQL_HOST: "database"
                    MYSQL_DATABASE: 'djangosite'
                    MYSQL_USER: 'xxxx'
                    MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'xxxxxx'
                    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxxxx'
                    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
                    MYSQL_PORT: "3306"

            volumes:
                    - db_loc:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
            site:
                    external: true
volumes:
            db_loc:
                    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, for this type of configuration you'll need a cluster. A database process can't access the same data as another one - in the same disk, of course - because there is a explicity lock to avoid data corruption.

This implies that you'll need to configure not a replica of **database** service, but another service for each node you want.

Databases are a challenge for scaling, and you have 2 most common options with MySQL, InnoDB Cluster or Galera Cluster. Because you're using MariaDB, Galera Cluster is the option, but this is a multi-master cluster and most of time can't scale write well.

With Galera cluster you'll need to start the first one as the **main** with the flag *--wsrep-new-cluster*, followed by the other two. Then you restart the first one without that flag.
Another downside, you'll need to create a **config** - or volume, or your own image with a custom configuration - specifying the "cluster address" pointing to all instances.
Each instance has it's own volume.

With MySQL 8.0 you can use InnoDB cluster, that can be both, multi-master or single-master. It's a little more confortable to configure in orchestrators like **swarm** or **kubernetes**.

One downside of **swarm** is the lack of "load balancer", for this type of configuration - three services, not replicas - you'll need to create a tcp load balancer - like HAProxy - or configure the load balancing in the application driver.
This can be easely achived in **kubernetes**.

I've created a little functional example here - with PHP, but it's ok:

### Files

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: '3.0'

services:
  app:
    image: alpine
    command: /bin/sh -c 'apk add php-cli php-mysqli && php -S 0.0.0.0:80 -t /app'
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    environment:
      DB_HOST: balancer
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASS: dragonfly
    volumes:
    - ./app:/app
  balancer: 
    image: haproxy:alpine
    volumes:
    - ./etc/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
  db0:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    command: --wsrep-new-cluster --wsrep_node_address=db0
    #command: --wsrep_node_address=db0
    hostname: db0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dragonfly
    volumes:
    - ./etc/galera.cnf:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/galera.cnf
#  db1:
#    image: mariadb:10.3
#    command: --wsrep_node_address=db1 --user=mysql
#    hostname: db1
#    restart: always
#    entrypoint: mysqld
#    environment:
#      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dragonfly
#    volumes:
#    - ./etc/galera.cnf:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/galera.cnf
#  db2:
#    image: mariadb:10.3
#    command: --wsrep_node_address=db2 --user=mysql
#    hostname: db2
#    restart: always
#    entrypoint: mysqld
#    environment:
#      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dragonfly
#    volumes:
#    - ./etc/galera.cnf:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/galera.cnf
```

**haproxy.cfg**

```
defaults
mode http
log global
retries 2
timeout connect 3000ms
timeout server 5000ms
timeout client 5000ms

frontend mysql
bind 0.0.0.0:3306
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend galera

backend galera
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option tcp-check
server mariadb0 db0:3306 check fall 3 rise 2
server mariadb1 db1:3306 check fall 3 rise 2
server mariadb2 db2:3306 check fall 3 rise 2
```

**galera.cnf**

```
[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name=dragonfly
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://db0:4567,db1:4567,db2:4567
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
wsrep_provider_options="pc.wait_prim_timeout=PT120S;evs.install_timeout=PT15S"
wsrep_sst_auth=root:dragonfly
```

**index.php**

```php
<?php

$mysql = new mysqli(getenv('DB_HOST'), getenv('DB_USER'), getenv('DB_PASS'));

if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
  echo "Error: {$mysql->connect_errno} - {$mysql->connect_error}";
  exit(1);
}

$res = $mysql->query('SELECT @@hostname');

while ($rs = $res->fetch_row())
  echo "<h1>{$rs[0]}</h1>";
```

### First Step - Main Master

The compose file have most of it commented and should be until the first master starts. In Galera Cluster the first machine - and only the first one - should start with the `--wsrep-new-cluster`

```
docker-compose up
```

The balancer will fail, just ignore it. You can use the option `-d` to detach the process, but is nice see the logs.

### Second Step - Other Masters

After the command above looks stable, edit the compose file removing all comments from the db1 and db2 services and the execute in another terminal - if you don't used `-d`:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Use this -d here to dettach the process, the logs of the first container we bring up is enough.
Testing

To test this little cluster you can go to your browser and open 127.0.0.1:8080, every time you refresh the page, one of the three database hostnames should appear.

From terminal you can do:

```
curl localhost:8080
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your effort to explain me how it all works. I will try to recreate your example in my environment. btw I think some "wait-for-it" scripts might be usefull to start db cluster. And I am aware I that I need load balancer for swarm but I`m new to orchestration and still discovering tools ;) Again, Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: :) You're welcome, and yeah! With a script verifying the status the example will be full, but I didn't put to simplify the things.